# vue computed placeholder changes multiple select-boxes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Vue version 2.6.10
I'll try writing in the code that gives the relevant information to prevent this from being huge

this is part of my component that has to do with select boxes

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <input
    :id="name"
    v-model="searchFilter"
    type="text"
    tabindex="-1"
    :class="{ searchbar: true, 'validation-error': validateError }"
    autocomplete="off"
    spellcheck="false"
    :disabled="disabled || loading"
    :readonly="single"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    @click="openList"
  />
  <input-icon :loading="loading"></input-icon>
</div>
```

this is the computed part which does the placeholder part

```js
computed: {
  placeholder() {
    if (this.single) {
      const selected = this.singleList.filter(item => item.selected === true).shift();
      return selected === undefined ? `Select ${_.startCase(this.name)}` : selected.name;
    }
  },
},
```

The issue is, that lets say I've got 3 instances of this component running?
once I choose one of them? the rest change their UI (aka placeholder value)

This is strictly a ui problem since I can tell that the value stays the same but I can't seem to find a way to access that value in order to show it.

I hope this is enough information to go on

Will provide additional code if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell based on what's presented. Is `single` a prop? What about `singleList`? Showing an example of how the component is used would help. Please try to remove as many lines as possible. E.g. do we really need to know the `class` of your input?

Comment: Sounds like you need to put a key on your input element although its hard to know.